# why the keyword template can appear in a qualified-id formed by a class-head-name

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following two examples:

```cpp
template<class>
struct A{
  template<class...>
  struct B{};
};
template<class T>
template<class U>
struct A<T>::template B<U>{  // Notice this declaration
}; 
int main(){
}
```

This code is accepted by all [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/G7GT5j) except GCC 7.x. However, IIUC, I have to say that the declaration for `B<U>` shouldn't be supported by the grammar, My reason is:
[class#nt:class-head-name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#nt:class-head-name)

> nested-name-specifier <sub>opt</sub> class-name

There is no optional keyword **template** before `class-name`, so it should be an invalid declaration, as far as now, I think `GCC 7.x` is right.

Another example is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<class>
struct A{
    template<class>
    struct B{
       template<class...>
       struct C;
    };
};
template<class T>
template<class U>
template<class Y>
struct A<T>::template B<U>::C<Y>{  // #2

};
int main(){

}
```

According to this rule:
[temp.names#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#4)

> The keyword template is said to appear at the top level in a qualified-id if it appears outside of a template-argument-list or decltype-specifier. In a qualified-id of a declarator-id or **in a qualified-id formed by a class-head-name or enum-head-name**, the keyword template **shall not appear at the top level**.

As aforementioned, the first case may be prohibited by the relevant grammar. Instead, according to [temp.names#4], the second case should still be an invalid declaration. The rule explicit says that the keyword `template` shall not appear at the top level in qualified-id formed by a class-head-name. So, I wonder why the second case can be accepted by all [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/YW7oxe)?

How to interpret these two examples, the grammar for class-head-name and the rule [temp.names#4]?

Comment: [A possibly related bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45975).

Comment: @xskxzr Well, it is. It violates "In a qualified-id of a declarator-id the keyword template shall not appear at the top level". it is similar to the second case. How about the first case? I think it is a bug of all compilers, regardless of the related grammar or the rule defined in [temp.names#4], they all prohibit the first code, Right?